# When is the partition refinement graph Eulerian?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, set-partition, eulerian-path

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $p(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$. For two partitions $p_1, p_2$ of the same integer $n$, we say that $p_2$ is a *refinement* of $p_1$ if the parts of $p_1$ can be subdivided to produce the parts of $p_2$. For example, $(2, 2, 1)$ is a refinement of $(4, 1)$ but $(2, 2, 1)$ is not a refinement of $(3, 1, 1)$. For each positive integer $n$, define a graph $G_n$ whose vertices are the partitions of n, so $|V (G_n)| = p(n)$, and whose edge set is $$E(G_n) = \{{u, v} : u \ne v, \,\,\text{and}\,\, u \text{ is a refinement of } v \text{ or } v \text{ is a refinement of } u\}$$
> Prove that $G_n$ is Eulerian if and only if $n = 1$ or $n = 3$.

I’ve tried drawing out the graphs $n=4$ and $n=5$ but haven’t made any connections. I’m not sure how one should approach a question like this.

Any help appreciated, thank you :).

Comment: Hi! Please typeset your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ For example, `$\{p_1, p_2\}$` yields $\{p_1, p_2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your advice 

Comment: Use `\ne` to get $\ne$

Comment: Sounds like you need to show there’s a vertex with odd degree for all $n \ge 4$.

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I’m trying to show l, it’s not exactly trivial either

Comment: Hint: can the vertices $(1,1,1,\dots)$ and $(2,2,1,\dots)$ both have even degree?

Comment: You should try to write titles that will tell people what the question is about. Nobody is going to read "Not sure how to prove the case when n>= 4" and think "Ah yes! I'm an expert in dealing with numbers greater than or equal to 4."

Comment: I have the idea in my head now. For n=4, (2,2) and (1,1,1,1) have differing degrees. But for n>4, any partition not already accounted for will be able to be constructed from both (1,1,1…) and (2,2,1…) making these two tulles have different degrees. I am not sure how to write this mathematically though

Comment: Every other partition is connected to $(1,1,1,\ldots)$, so it has degree $p(n)-1$.  Every other partition except $(3,1,1,\ldots)$ is connected to $(2,2,1,1,\ldots)$, so it has degree $p(n)-2$.  These can't both be even.